Building a regular expression (0,1) that only includes even-length words without the substring 101
I've been trying to solve the following exercise:

Build a regular expression for the language that accepts the characters 1,0 so that the length of all words in the language is even and the language does not include the sequence "101".
You can only use the following characters

connecting, for example 1 and 0
with OR +, for example (1+0)
Appears zero or more times *, example (1+0)*


I tried to divide into cases
(00)* + (11)* + (01) + (10) +

And in the next part I tried several ways; but I did not find a solution:
01(11+00)* (10) +
10+(11+00)* 

How can I complete a regular expression that corresponds to this language?

Hint#1: How many different pairs of 0 and 1 are there? 4 - 00, 01, 10 & 11. So put them together in an alternation and scan pairs until you run out.  If it's an even length string you should be at end of string ($).   Hint#2: Put a negative lookahead at the beginning to scan ahead for 101 any where in the string (.*101).

A negative look is not part of the signs that are allowed to be used @
@ChrisMaurer

@ChrisMaurer: The question is about regular expressions in its computer science sense, so there is no lookaheads or other advanced features.

This is actually not a trivial question. The asker has shared their attempt, and the question is clear. It escapes me why the closure reason is "too broad".

I started with 3 states and ended up with 77 characters.

As only even lengths of input are acceptable, we could translate the problem to one where the input language consists of 00, 01, 10, and 11 and where there can be no sequence of 0101, 1101, 1010, nor 1011.
Or, let's use single symbols for this alphabet: ,, and . And we cannot have the sequences , ,  nor 
We can design a DFA for this language:

1 is the initial state. "sink" is the reject state. 1, 2 and 3 are accept states.
We can leave out the reject state, as the regular expression doesn't need it:

To use the method of state elimination we should first make sure we only have one accept state, so I'll add 4 which is an endpoint that is only reachable with empty-string transitions:

I'll choose the "easiest" state to eliminate, 2. All combinations of incoming and outgoing transitions to/from that state need to be replaced by direct transitions. And so we get:

Let's now eliminate 3, taking care of the loop it has, which must be included (with *) in all replacing transitions:

As there are some recurring terms, we can apply some simplification rules and get:

And from that we can read the regular expression, again taking into account that we have a loop at state 1:
      ((ε+)(+)*(ε+))*(ε+)(+)*(ε+)
Substituting these symbols by the original 0,1 symbols, we get:
      ((ε+01)(11+1001)*(ε+10)00)*(ε+01)(11+1001)*(ε+10)
Verification
If we would write this in a regex format as used in programming languages, we could use the ? to translate the ε symbol, | for the plus operator, and add start/end assertions (^ and $):
^((01)?(11|1001)*(10)?00)*(01)?(11|1001)*(10)?$

Here is a JavaScript program that verifies with sampling whether it does the job. In the random tests it only verifies even length strings, as it is obvious from the structure of the regex that odd lengths are not matched by it:


const regex = /^((01)?(11|1001)*(10)?00)*(01)?(11|1001)*(10)?$/;
const forbidden = "101";

console.log("empty string should pass", regex.test("") ? "OK" : "NOK");
console.log("0101 should not pass", regex.test("0101") ? "NOK" : "OK");
console.log("1110011001 should pass", regex.test("1110011001") ? "OK" : "NOK");

for (let test = 0; test < 10000; test++) {
    // Build a random string of 0 and 1:
    let s = "";
    for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        s += Math.floor(Math.random() * 2);
    }
    while (s.includes(forbidden)) {
        if (regex.test(s)) throw s + " should not pass, but it does";
        s = s.replace(forbidden, ["000","001","010","011","100","110","111"][Math.floor(Math.random() * 7)]);
    }
    if (!regex.test(s)) throw s + " should pass, but it does not";
}
console.log("random tests passed");



The necessity of the ε symbol
The above solution uses the empty-string symbol ε. Unless you allow other constructs, this is a necessity. Without it, the only way to allow an empty string (which has even length and has no "101" occurrence) is to use the Kleene star (*) at the top-level of your regular expression (or in at least one of the operands of a top-level + operation), so that that pattern can be used zero times. But that would imply that if two inputs, that each consist of an arbitrary repetition of a subtring, are valid then also the concatenation of those inputs must be valid. And that is not true:  times 001 is a valid input, and  times 010 is also valid, but their concatenation is not).
We could define () to be equivalent with the empty string, and then you don't need to explicitly use ε.

thank you for the detailed explanation!
I try to build and run my own regex:
regex = re.compile(r'^((00)*|(1001)*|(0001)*|(11)*|(1000)*)*(10)?$')
I got an Exception:
0000010001000010000110010000011001000111000100111110000100010011000010011100000001001100111100100111 should pass, but it does not
Can you help me to understand why it should pass, but it does not?

It should pass because there is no "101" substring in your input. It doesn't pass because the pattern in the first group (i.e. ((00)*|(1001)*|(0001)*|(11)*|(1000)*)) can only repeat twice to match "0000". It cannot continue with a repeat to match "01...", and since the remainder of the input does not match the final pattern (10)?$ either, the input is not matched.

You can see that even with an input of just "01" your regex will not match it, yet it is a valid input.

I added a simplification step to my answer, bringing the regex down to ^((01)?(11|1001)*(10)?00)*(01)?(11|1001)*(10)?$. Of course, with the full power of regexes it could be much shorter, but here it was just to verify whether the regular expression did not have any mistakes.

Because this is almost certainly homework, I will outline the steps but leave the work to you.

Construct an automaton that recognizes the specified language.

You may be able to construct an NFA directly.
If not, recall that regular languages are closed under intersection.

Construct separate DFAs that recognize even-length binary strings and binary strings that don’t contain 101.
Using these DFAs, construct a DFA that simulates the processing of both in parallel.
Choose the accept states to represent the intersection rather the union.




Convert your automaton to a regular expression. See an answer on CS Stack Exchange for reference, but use the algorithm from your textbook.

JFLAP is a tool that can help with conversions between NFAs, DFAs, and regular expressions, all of which are equivalent in power.



